# XSD Designer is Broken Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xsd

When I open a XSD file in the designer the file loads but does not display properly. I can scroll the window like the file is there but the 'Please wait while loading...' dialog does not disappear. If a table is clicked in the designer it is show and I can make changes. If VS is minimized then maximized, whatever is displayed in the XSD Designer until a table is clicked in the designer. I need this fixed so any information will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have found a way to get this type of file to view correctly in VS2010. All I do is lock (Ctrl+L) and unlock the computer. I'm not sure of the cause of this. The same thing happens when I'm editing Windows forms in GUI mode with the dotted line.